# Cannot start native decoder aacdecoder

Tags: java, android, aac

Hello everyone I'm trying to play an aac radio on my app usign [this](https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/) library, the problem is that when I code the basics It throws this:

```
11-24 16:33:55.591    4596-4626/ger.radio E/Decoder[OpenCORE]﹕ start() init failed status=30
11-24 16:33:55.592    4596-4626/ger.radio E/Decoder﹕ start() failed err=-1
11-24 16:33:55.593    4596-4636/ger.radio E/BufferReader﹕ Exception when reading:     java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
11-24 16:33:55.595    4596-4626/ger.radio E/AACPlayer﹕ playAsync():
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start native decoder
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.start(Decoder.java:237)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.playImpl(AACPlayer.java:424)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:386)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:338)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:296)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And this is my code

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rep){
                AACPlayer aacPlayer = new AACPlayer();
                aacPlayer.stop();
            }else{
                AACPlayer aacPlayer = new AACPlayer();
                aacPlayer.playAsync( "http://cast.direcnode.com:11320/stream" );
                rep = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The real cause is "java.net.SocketException: Socket closed", something is wrong connecting with your endpoint url, (firewall, proxy... etc, etc), the decoder does nothing strange, nothing in particular, simply plays an inputstream, take a look at the source code https://aacdecoder-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/decoder/src/com/spoledge/aacdecoder/AACPlayer.java.

Comment: @vzamanillo and what could I do in that case?

Comment: You have to check your network :/